# Replacing port circle with custom image, devs.Model

Tags: jointjs

I am new to jointjs. I am working with shapes as instances of joint.shapes.devs.Model and am trying to replace the circle, representing an in/out port with a custom image. I would like to keep the current functionality where it is possible to create a new arrow by dragging the circle, snaplinks, and the rest of the great functionality offered by JointJs. The only thing I would like to do is to replace the magnet/inPort/circle with an image. Is this possible? If so, how?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed possible. The best way would be to look at how the joint.shapes.devs.Model is defined here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/clientIO/joint/master/plugins/shapes/joint.shapes.devs.js and create your own custom shape that has the SVG <image> element in the ports instead of the current <circle>.